# How could I make this buffer overflow?

Tags: security, fread, buffer-overflow, exploit

```
void display(const char *path)
{
  char msg[128];
  int8_t size;
  memset(msg, 0, 128);

  FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
  size_t n = fread(&size, 1, 1, file);
  if (n == 0 || size > 128)
    return;
  n = fread(msg, 1, size, file);

  puts(msg);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
    return 1;

  display(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

How could I make this buffer overflow? I mean, the buffer is 128 bytes. But doesn't the code check if size is greater than 128? If it is, then it will just return early, and if not, it will only copy less than 128 bytes from file to msg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int8_t size;` is a 8-bit signed value, thus it falls in the range [-128,127].

When this code is executed :

```
  size_t n = fread(&size, 1, 1, file);
  if (n == 0 || size > 128)
    return;
```

If size has is most significant bit set (that is size is >= 0x80), then it is treated has a negative number, thus escaping/avoiding the check.

Let say the code reads size with a value of 0x8F (this is 143 in decimal), but as the int8_t type has a size of 8 bits and a value range of [-128,127], the most significant bit is set and indicates a signed value, which means the value is -113.

Thus `size` is less than 128  in `(n == 0 || size > 128)` simply because `-113 > 128` is false.

Which means the code will read more bytes than the size of the array. It will read 143 bytes but the array size is only 128, thus triggering a stack based buffer overflow.